# Obter valor de um pedido por marca ou empresa

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Estou no desenvolvimento de um módulo para receber comissões das empresas que forem vender em minha loja magento. Isso já está funcionando, porém, preciso adicionar uma função nova que não estou conseguindo.

Preciso adicionar um valor extra na comissão, caso o pedido de alguma empresa for maior que “X”
Eu fiz de uma forma que não deu certo:

```
foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $key => $item){
               $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
               $price = $item->getPrice();
               $valor_comissao = (int)$product->getAttributeText('comissao_vendedor')/100;
               $comissao_valor2 = $price-($price*$valor_comissao);
               $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
               $valor_pedido = ($price*$qty);

               if($valor_pedido > 150) {
                 $comissao_valor = ($comissao_valor2*$qty-17);
               } else {
                  $comissao_valor=($comissao_valor2*$qty-2);
               }
               $comissoes[] = array (
                                                    'Razao' => 'Produto '.$item->getName().' id '.$item->getProductId().' x '.$item->getQtyToInvoice().' sku: '. $item->getSku(),
                                                    'Login' => $product->getAttributeText('login'),
                                                    'ValorFixo' => $comissao_valor
                                                );
    }
```

Desta forma, apenas se o produto passar de $150,00 que o valor é adicionado e caso tenha 2 produtos da mesma marca custando $100,00, o valor não é adicionado. Estou precisando que o valor seja adicionado se o pedido inteiro da marca ultrapasse $150,00.

A lógica que eu estou tentando seguir é a seguinte:

> - pegar valor total do pedido;
> - filtrar por marcas, ou seja, valor total do pedido por marca;
> - se o produto for de uma marca que ultrapassou o valor "x" e ela ainda não ter recebido o valor adicional, adicionar frete.

Comment: Tenta dar uma olhada no se o problema não é o forEach que não está fechado.

Comment: O `foreach` não foi fechado.

Comment: OI, obrigado pela sugestão. 
Na verdade eu acabei não colocando o final do código onde mostra o fechamento:

               $comissoes[] = array (
                                                        'Razao' => 'Produto '.$item->getName().' id '.$item->getProductId().' x '.$item->getQtyToInvoice().' sku: '. $item->getSku(),
                                                        'Login' => $product->getAttributeText('login'),
                                                        'ValorFixo' => $comissao_valor
                                                    );
        }